# Spring boot / netflix zuul application is not starting

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, netflix-zuul

I'm developing a spring boot, security application to serve as sso api

here is my pom dependecies

```
     <artifactId>historage-ui-front-web</artifactId>
      <name>historage-ui-front-web</name>
      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>${junit.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
          <version>${swagger-parser.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Security-->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-cloud-starter-zuul.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <!-- Conflit avec jersay 2.0.1-->
              <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
              <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <!-- Desactiver actuator : pas pour le moment -->
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-security-saml2-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <version>${spring.security.test.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
          <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
          <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
          <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

          <!--Security : end-->
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <description>Projet historage-ui-front</description>
  <properties>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.18.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <logback-classic.version>1.1.7</logback-classic.version>
    <logback-core.version>1.1.7</logback-core.version>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.7.21</org.slf4j.version>
    <version.node>v6.11.1</version.node>
    <version.npm>4.2.0</version.npm>
    <spring-boot.version>1.5.7.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.11.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.test.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.test.version>
    <spring-cloud-starter-zuul.version>1.3.4.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-zuul.version>
    <spring-security-saml2-core.version>1.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security-saml2-core.version>
    <jjwt.version>0.6.0</jjwt.version>
    <swagger-parser.version>1.0.32</swagger-parser.version>
  </properties>
```

this is a test that I wrote test load context

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class LoadContextTest {

    @Test
    public void can_load_normal_context() {
        // Test vide, pour tester le chargement de context normal.
    }
}
```

this is my application.java class

```
// Entry Point
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

when executing the test class I'm getting this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/context/DelegatingApplicationListener

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:508)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:818)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:804)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:790)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.context.DelegatingApplicationListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 53 more
```

After Verification, the DelegatingApplicationListener is present

when launching the application I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:508)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:818)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:804)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:790)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at org.historage_ui.front.web.Application.main(Application.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 29 more
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youare mixing versions of the Spring framework. Do not do this unless you have an extremely warranted reason or else you will run into issues at runtime.

Please see this blog for more info on why not,

https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

You should handle the import of versions of spring boot and spring cloud via BOMs. Any component of the Spring framework that is required will be  managed if you add or part of the respective starters. Additionally you could just extend the Spring Parent POM and not use the `spring-boot-dependencies` BOM. See see documentation for more info https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html

```
<dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
           <version>Dalston.SR3</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
          <version>${swagger-parser.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <!-- Desactiver actuator : pas pour le moment -->
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-security-saml2-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
          <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
          <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Additionally when packaging as a WAR your main class should look something like,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
}
```

See a working example here. https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/